# Remote desktop control on print screen

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, print-screen

Is there a way to make the remote desktop control at the top of the screen (ie. the small tab with the ip and minimize, close etc icons) be captured when you do a print screen?

Normally it just gets ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc.exe), choose "options >>" and go to the "local resources" tab. Under the Keyboard section choose the option "on the local computer". When you press the print screen butten, it will now capture your screen on the local computer, so the small tab with the IP will be captured too. Just paste it into paint or whatever program you like to use on the local computer (not the one you remotely connect to).

[image]

et voila!

[image]

Comment: Very very ta!!!